# Some Entity Values going to set as Null by default. while Updation Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Hi I have following situations:

```
//User Entity:
firstname: S
LastName: R
email : ss@gm.com
Status: "Active"
//User Profile entity:
profilePic: 
favoritemovies: 
Hobbies:
```

So while updating User Profile entity I am rendering only the following fields from both entities:

```
firstname:
LastName:
email:
profilePic:
favoritemovies:
Hobbies:
```

So here I do not want user to update his Status field, so that i did not render it on update ProfileForm. now when I am updating the  ProfileForm, So  "Status" field of "User Entity" also set as NULL default. Can anybody please guide me what I am missing in this.

I am using symfony 2.6 with MySql:

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add this field to your eg. ProfileType.php class, then fields not included should be not updating.

Antoher way on you entity setter for the status you can make it like this:

```
/**
 * Set status
 *
 * @param string $status
 * @return User
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    if (!is_null($status)) {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Then there is not possiblity to save null data to status property.